# Issue with Shell32 dll while unzipping Files in c#

Tags: c#

I m trying to unzip huge files using `Shell32 dll` in `c#`, here I'm facing an issue - I'm trying to unzip a 180 file. After unzipping its size is 5GB and it is showing below error.

> An unexpected error is keeping you from copying the file.If you continue to receive this error, youcan use the error code to search for help wth this problem.
>   Error 0x80004005: Unspecifed error

Code used for unzipping file using `Shell32 dll`:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ZipFolderSource);

                foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
                {

                    Shell32.Shell objShell = new Shell32.Shell();
                    Shell32.Folder destinationFolder = objShell.NameSpace(ExtractedFilesPath);
                    Shell32.Folder sourceFile = objShell.NameSpace(fi.FullName);

                    foreach (var file in sourceFile.Items())
                    {
                        destinationFolder.CopyHere(file, 20);
                    }
                }
```

I'm able to unzip small files up to 2 GB using above code but if it crosses more than 3 GB file size then I'm receiving error.

Comment: have you searched for this error number? I see quite a few non-programmatic solutions in google results...

Comment: We need more than the error code though, as Meehow said, there different solutions but most of them involves an faulty Windows configuration.

Comment: Is this code running on Windows XP or Windows Server 2003? If so, then you are probably failing because XP / Server 2003 does not support ZIP64.

Comment: I m using Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit operrating system

Comment: You are flying pretty blind when you use "20".  Use 0 and you'll see more.  And do use a decent library instead of the shell extension, like .NET's ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory().

Comment: @ Hans Passant, i tried with 0 also still same issue i m facing, I m using 4.0 framework